# How can I train my dog to sleep quietly in a crate when he misses his dog friend?

Tags: dogs, behavior, training, psychology, crate

Two weeks ago, we got my wife's dog in house after it lived with another dog and slept in a crate with that dog for 9 years.

Obviously we didn't sleep that well for the first few days. Now our dog is settling down, but he still does wake up and bark at night every now and then.

What we tried is having a cuddle in the crate for him and a T-shirt of my wife (he sees her as his boss.)

But he still whines and barks at night.

I assume he's missing his mate.

Do you guys have any tips to get him to sleep/be silent until I take him for a walk?

Comment: Have you tried leaving a radio on for him so he feels like people are around? Worked for our pup overnight.

Comment: @Aravona No, I haven't. I don't have a radio. But if we crate him when we're in the same room, he's making even more noises.

Comment: we had a radio but ended up using the tv on a low volume after it broke. It might be worth a try. Another trick or two I heard of was a wrapped up ticking clock or a hot waterbottle. These are puppy tricks but we used the radio with our older mongrel before she passed on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have had this identical problem with my dog. He pined all night long for his mate (who had passed away), and he wouldn't be quiet until I took him outside.

As harsh as it may sound considering the circumstances, **I simply ignored him after lights-out**. No matter how much he barked and whined, I didn't give him the attention he wanted (for the seven hours till we woke up). It was difficult for me of course, but it worked. Within a week, the entire household slept well, and he stopped missing his mate at all.

The fact is, your dog wants attention. It sounds so cruel to deny him that, but unfortunately you cannot sacrifice your life to replace his friend. I would suggest that you cuddle him, say goodnight, turn the lights off, and do your best to fall asleep. With time, he will too. :)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! I tried this one night and I couldn't keep this up. I live in an appartment so I got people surrounding me and a barking dog the whole night won't make us popular. So we had to find another solution, which we did (see my own answer). But I do think this is generally the best answer, so I accept it.

Answer (score 3):

Think about get him a new friend, It is lonely being alone. While neither of you may want to get a puppy, there are many mature dogs at local shelters that need a home.

Our local shelter will allow you (actually they insist) that the current dog and the potential new dog meet at the shelter to see if it will work out.

You may also want to consider a different type of pet, both cats and rabbits will enjoy spending time with your dog and both use litter boxes, which may or may not be a benefit to you.

Answer (score 3):

My specific solution was moving the crate too our bedroom and get him a hot water bottle in his crate. The hot water bottle on itself got him to sleep better but he still woke up too early. This morning I actually had to wake him up.

Putting this up as an answer because neither of the answers were the solution.